# linq query to find the objects that are the maximum and the minimum

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of DailyValue structs called stockValues. I need to find the object with the maximum and the minimum `High` value.

(Here is the struct for reference's sake)

```
struct DailyValues
{
        public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
        public decimal Open { get; private set; }
        public decimal High { get; private set; }
        public decimal Low { get; private set; }
        public decimal Close { get; private set; }
        public decimal Volume { get; private set; }
        public decimal AdjClose { get; private set; }
}
```

I've tried a couple various things,

```
var mx = stockValues.Max(sv => sv.High);
```

Only gives me the correct maximum value, but it does not let me access the whole object and it's members (what I want is the actual value AND the date it occurred). So I attempted this:

```
var stuff = from s in stockValues
                        group s by s.Date into g
                        where g.Max(x => x.High)
                        select g;
```

However, this just underlines `g.Max(..)` and states that the compiler cannot implicitly convert a decimal into a boolean. While I am not new to C#, I have no experience with Linq and cannot seem to wrap my mind around it quite correctly (I'm sure this is very simple, I'm just not doing it right). Can anyone steer me correctly?

As always, thanks to all in advance!

Comment: How do you need to handle the case where you have multiple elements with the same max or min High value?  Do you just need a single element or a list of them?

Comment: @AdamS Sorry, I didn't see your comment. In this instance we can disregard duplicates (for this we are guaranteed to only have one item).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `MaxBy` and `MinBy` methods from [moreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library.

```
var max = stockValues.MaxBy(sv => sv.High);
var min = stockValues.MinBy(sv => sv.High);
```

They return entire object instead of just the max/min value of property you're trying to sort by.

If you'd like to stay with standard set of LINQ methods, you can do following:

```
var max = stockValues.OrderByDescending(sv => sv.High).First();
var min = stockValues.OrderBy(sv => sv.High).First();
```

Or to perform ordering just once:

```
var ordered = stockValues.OrderBy(sv => sv.High).ToList();
var max = ordered.Last();
var min = ordered.First();
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer, it really helped me get through not only this particular problem but was illuminating for some other issues I was having.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to perform in 2 steps:

```
var mx = stockValues.Max(sv => sv.High);
var result = stockValues.Where(sv=>sv.High == mx);
```

You can use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where` if you just want 1 item.

### UPDATE

If you just want 1 item, I think using `Aggregate` is **the best choice**:

```
var result = stockValues.Aggregate((a, b) => b.High > a.High ? b : a);
```

To get multi-items (of the same max `High`), the code can be like this:

```
var results = stockValues.Aggregate(new List<DailyValues>(), (a,b)=>{
                                    if (a.Count == 0) a.Add(b);
                                    else if (b.High >= a[0].High){
                                      if(b.High > a[0].High) a.Clear();
                                      a.Add(b);
                                    }                
                                    return a;
                                 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I +1'd it. I would have chosen it if I was more clear on how it actually worked, but it was a bit more complicated than what I needed. Non-the-less; I really appreciate it, it gives me more insight to what's possible and that is invaluable.

Comment: @SonofLysander no, if you want to get multi-items, it's of course a little long (not complicated), but if you just want to get one of the maximum items, it's very clear that we need just 1 line. It's the best way to find the max/min as I said. It loops just once and outputs the max/min for you. While if you use `OrderBy` then get the `First()` or `Last()`, it's much more work to do and hence less efficient.